# Directory Redirects and WWW's

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver, http-redirect

I am trying to attempt a directory redirect on my website with a redirect structure like such:

```
example.com/index.php/exampleA > example.com/wiki/exampleA
example.com/index.php/exampleB > example.com/wiki/exampleB
```

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) to try and implement the directory redirect on my website. This is the following code that I have added to my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

[image: Code that I have attempted to use]

The following code works however I have to be in the www subdirectory in order for the directory to function. My website has a cloudflare rule that redirects the www subdirectory to the normal https://marblehorse.net. So I used basic levels of thinking and figured out that I needed to change my server name in order for the script to work. So then I tried the following two examples in replacement of the ServerName in the original code snippet

[image: Code snippet 1]
[image: Code snippet 2]

However both led to the following error on my website

[image: 404 error, page not found]

I am extremely new to apache and am misguided on what my problem is. Is it impossible to use the base domain without the www subdirectory? Do I need to reroute the www subdomain to the main domain in a apache rule?